# Ruby sort_by with null values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Using Ruby on Rails. I'm trying to sort a query by number (saved as string) and letter. However, my letter column can contain "NULL" values. This crashes when there are Null values in the letter column:

```
@fences = Fence.find(:all,
                     :conditions => ["coursewalk_id = #{@coursewalk.id}"]).sort_by { |a| [+(a.number.to_i), a.letter] }
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`a.letter.to_s` should do the trick.